# Three.js - sprite depths rendering backwards in r70+

Tags: javascript, three.js

It looks like something broke with r70+ regarding z-depth of sprites.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qu241cLv/) that works perfect with r69.

Here is the same [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qu241cLv/2/) except using r71.
You can see that now when the scene rotates, the depths of the sprites are not always shown correctly. Half the time they are rotated into view with wrong z-depths.

Is this a bug or is something new I need to add that I missed?

I've tried all variations of common commands below and nothing seems to work all around like it used to.

```
var shaderMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({

    ...
    depthTest:      false,
    depthWrite:      false,
    transparent:    true
});

particleSystem.sortParticles = true;
```

I'm aware of the new renderDepth, but that solution seems to be unrelated and doesn't explain why it would break previous behaviour. We don't need to continually update renderDepths manually for all camera angles now do we?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PointCloud.sortParticles` was removed in three.js r70; see [this commit](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/commit/e65e086d49c1b1b0574a1017a9040868b63b9cff).

In your original example (without transparency), you can get your desired behavior by enabling the depth test for your material:

```
var shaderMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({

    ...
    depthTest: true
});
```

In your updated example (with transparency), it's necessary to sort the particles yourself in three.js r70.

Note that three.js still handles z-sorting when rendering [THREE.Sprite](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Objects/Sprite) objects. That could be worth investigating.

Comment: Thanks @msmolens. Unfortunately this doesn't work correctly when transparency is enabled. My original jsfiddle should of included a sprite texture so we can see why this doesn't work with transparency. See this updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qb6960Lx/8/) to see why this fix won't work, while also allowing transparent png's.

Comment: Does it work If you add an alpha test in points_fragmentshader, like: if (gl_FragColor.a < 0.1) { discard; } [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qb6960Lx/9/)

Comment: That could work for situations without transparency, but the results are not ideal. The edges are all jaggy. What is worse is you can't use transparency. Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qb6960Lx/10/) of how a blurred texture was looking in r69. Now here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qb6960Lx/11/) using the '(gl_FragColor.a < 0.1)' technique with r71. And the original [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qb6960Lx/12/) working r69 version, except using r71, and showing the broken behaviour.

Comment: For your example with transparency it's now necessary to sort the particles yourself since the engine no longer sorts them. I updated my answer with this information.